# Flex code region?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, region

Is there a way in flex (Flash Builder 4) to make regions like in c#, to group a part of the code allowing us to collapse it and see through our project more easily?

In c# it's like:

```
#region example

// my functions I want to group

#endregion
```

Comment: Note that [apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616551) FlashDevelop supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I have seen.  I have only found comment and function collapsing.

Comment: For sure, hopefully as the IDE develops this will get added in

Answer (score 1):

No, you basically have to use comments.  I generally do something like

```
// *********************** THIS REGION IS FOR ... *************************
```

Comment: the only thing I want to use regions for collapsing, not for better understanding of the code

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way you can do this, at least in Flex Builder 4.5.  I've had success using multiple <fx:Script> tags.  You can add a <!--Region Title--> comment above the tag, and just collapse the entire tag.  Not exactly as good as proper code regions, but it works pretty well.

Comment: This only works inside mxml files. Large project most often do not have actionscript in script tags in mxml. So this isn't a great solution.