# Is there an equivalent to C#'s #region directive in AS3?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Just started coding in AS3 with FlashDevelop and coming from a C# background, I would like to know if there's something equivalent to the #region directive in AS3?

The #region directive in C# essentially allows an IDE e.g Visual Studio to collapse or expand a section of code to improve readability. With #region directives, you can split codes in sections e.g constructors, properties, public/private methods to aid others perusing your code.

So the C# code below ...

```
interface IPurchaseOrder
{
    #region Properties

    bool IsProcessed { get; set; }
    bool ISValidOrder { get; set; }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    bool ProcessOrder();

    #endregion Methods
}
```

becomes

```
interface IPurchaseOrder
{
    Properties

    Methods
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain the #region directive for the non-C# people.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan, thanks for the top, have edited accordingly.

Comment: It's not C#'s directive, it's special mark of Visual Studio. For c# itself it's a regular comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With flashdevelop it works like this:

```
//{ region region name

  ...your code here

//} endregion
```

Comment: I take it that the expand/collapse region functionality is a FlashDevelop-specific feature?

Comment: Yes of course. Code hidding is always IDE/texteditor specific.